# How to set default values in popus form view from parent tree view in odoo 12?

Tags: odoo-12

I have this tree view in odoo 12:

[image]

When I click in button "Editer liste de prix" of line 1, I get this form view:

[image]

How to have values of line 1 in popus view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define `_default_field_name` function for every field in you wizard, and you can get the reference to the father searching into the `context`, is an example:

```
def _default_a_field(self):
    parent_id = self._context.get('active_id', False)
    return self.env['parent.model'].search([('id', '=', parent_id)]).a_field_from_parent
a_field = fields.Char(default=_default_a_field)
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.